# SSH access problem

Tags: ssh

Hello I have a server at rackspace cloud running Ubuntu Karmic Koala
I was trying to do something until I accidently removed the server ip and name from the file /etc/hosts/ and rebooted. After reboot I am not able to connect to the server using putty although I added the missing line back using webmin file manager.
In webmin when I go to SSH Login. It says **There is no SSH server running on *my ip* port 22.**
Can any one help

Answer (score 3):

If Webmin is up and running you can issue commands to the server.  Run /etc/init.d/sshd start and see if that fixes the issue.  Also, you should have access to a package manager through webmin as well so you can re-install ssh if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have accidently removed something other, too. SSH server is AFAIK not so dependant on `/etc/hosts`.

BTW. from `/etc/hosts` you have probably deleted the first line (if we don't count the comments). Have you put it back there, or at the end of file?

Answer (score 0):

start the sshd daemon, either from webmin or have somebody at the hosting company support do it

in /etc/hosts should be also the hostname and the external ip address, after 127.0.0.1 - localhost